# could not find schema type named {{http}//schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

I am developing a fusion web application and I'm using an external webservice.
The projects in my application:
- Model & ViewController.
- Java Webservice from WSDL.
- WebService Client and Proxy.

I made some java classes to extract the data I need from the webservice and this works fine (when just running java classes).
But when I add a page with just a label on it and try to deploy I get the following stacktrace.

I'm using Weblogic Server 10.3 and JDeveloper.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
10:46:38 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:46:38 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:46:38 AM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application CRMapp due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[Application CRMapp stopped and undeployed from Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]
[Running application CRMapp on Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer...] 
[10:56:24 AM] Web Module SugarCRMWebServiceWebApp.war recognized in project SugarCRMWebService.jpr
[10:56:24 AM] Web Module ViewControllerWebApp.war recognized in project ViewController.jpr
[10:56:24 AM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[10:56:24 AM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 10.3).
[10:56:24 AM] Retrieving existing application information
[10:56:24 AM] Running dependency analysis...
[10:56:24 AM] Deploying 3 profiles...
[10:56:24 AM] Wrote Web Application Module to /Users/wimvdc/.jdeveloper/system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1/o.j2ee/drs/CRMapp/ViewControllerWebApp.war
[10:56:24 AM] Wrote Web Application Module to /Users/wimvdc/.jdeveloper/system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1/o.j2ee/drs/CRMapp/SugarCRMWebServiceWebApp.war
[10:56:25 AM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to /Users/wimvdc/.jdeveloper/system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1/o.j2ee/drs/CRMapp
[10:56:25 AM] Redeploying Application...
<WS data binding error>could not find schema type '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}normalizedString
<WS data binding error>could not find schema type '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}language
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find schema type named {{http}//schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}>>
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$GlobalTypeNode.getSchemaType(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:182)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$LocalElementNode.getSchemaProperty(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:207)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder.getHiddenArrayElementComponentTypeNamed(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:104)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.createBindingTypeFrom(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:1113)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.processTypeMappings(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:526)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.initBindingFileFrom109dd(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:273)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.<init>(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.createRuntimeBindings(RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.createRuntimeBindingProvider(WsBuilder.java:705)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.buildService(WsBuilder.java:201)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsFactory.createServerService(WsFactory.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.ServletDeployInfo.createWsService(ServletDeployInfo.java:91)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.DeployInfo.createWsPort(DeployInfo.java:372)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.init(BaseWSServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
could not identify anonymous schema type named '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}>>>tExtensibleDocumented[0,unbounded]', ignoring
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find schema type named {{http}//schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}>>
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$GlobalTypeNode.getSchemaType(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:182)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$LocalElementNode.getSchemaProperty(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:207)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder.getHiddenArrayElementComponentTypeNamed(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:104)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.createBindingTypeFrom(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:1113)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.processTypeMappings(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:526)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.initBindingFileFrom109dd(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:273)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.<init>(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.createRuntimeBindings(RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.createRuntimeBindingProvider(WsBuilder.java:705)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.buildService(WsBuilder.java:201)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsFactory.createServerService(WsFactory.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.ServletDeployInfo.createWsService(ServletDeployInfo.java:91)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.DeployInfo.createWsPort(DeployInfo.java:372)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.init(BaseWSServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
could not identify anonymous schema type named '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}>>>tExtensibleDocumented[0,unbounded]', ignoring
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find schema type named {{http}//schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}>>tBinding
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$GlobalTypeNode.getSchemaType(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:182)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$LocalElementNode.getSchemaProperty(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:207)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder.getHiddenArrayElementComponentTypeNamed(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:104)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.createBindingTypeFrom(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:1113)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.processTypeMappings(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:526)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.initBindingFileFrom109dd(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:273)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.<init>(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.createRuntimeBindings(RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.createRuntimeBindingProvider(WsBuilder.java:705)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.buildService(WsBuilder.java:201)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsFactory.createServerService(WsFactory.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.ServletDeployInfo.createWsService(ServletDeployInfo.java:91)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.DeployInfo.createWsPort(DeployInfo.java:372)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.init(BaseWSServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
....

<5-jul-2012 10:56:27 uur CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application 'CRMapp'.> 
<5-jul-2012 10:56:27 uur CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'CRMapp'.> 
<5-jul-2012 10:56:27 uur CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "sugarsoapPort" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "CRMapp-SugarCRMWebService-context-root".
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find schema type named {{http}//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}any
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$GlobalTypeNode.getSchemaType(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:182)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder.getTypeNamed(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:87)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.createBindingTypeFrom(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:1111)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.processTypeMappings(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:526)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.initBindingFileFrom109dd(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:273)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.<init>(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.createRuntimeBindings(RuntimeBindingsBuilderImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.createRuntimeBindingProvider(WsBuilder.java:705)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.buildService(WsBuilder.java:201)
    at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsFactory.createServerService(WsFactory.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.ServletDeployInfo.createWsService(ServletDeployInfo.java:91)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.DeployInfo.createWsPort(DeployInfo.java:372)
    at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.init(BaseWSServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find schema type named {{http}//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}any
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder$GlobalTypeNode.getSchemaType(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:182)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.AnonymousTypeFinder.getTypeNamed(AnonymousTypeFinder.java:87)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.createBindingTypeFrom(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:1111)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.processTypeMappings(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:526)
    at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.Deploytime109MappingHelper.initBindingFileFrom109dd(Deploytime109MappingHelper.java:273)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
<div class="jive-quote"> </div>
[10:56:27 AM] Deployment cancelled.
[10:56:27 AM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[10:56:27 AM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application CRMapp due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[Application CRMapp stopped and undeployed from Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the 'Java Webservice from WSDL' project since the 'WebService Client and Proxy' project also generated the types I needed.
Now it works.

Comment: What do you mean by this ? Would please explain more ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana If you want to consume a SOAP based WS you only need to use a 'WebService Client and Proxy' project, not the Java Webservice from WSDL